# asp.netcore set two login path

Tags: c#, asp.net, authorize-attribute

I'm beging width asp.net core, and want set two login path for authorization:'/account/login' for users and '/Admin/Account/Login' for administrators,that 'Admin' is an area name,but don't know what's wrong width me. 
here is my code in startup.cs:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddAuthorization();
        ...
    }

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
{
    ...
    app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions()
    {
        AuthenticationScheme = "UserAuthScheme",
        AutomaticAuthenticate = true,
        AutomaticChallenge = true,
        CookieName = ".AUTOUSERAUTHCOOKIE",
        LoginPath = "/Account/Login",
        CookieHttpOnly = true
    });
    app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions()
    {
        AuthenticationScheme = "AdministratorAuthScheme",
        AutomaticAuthenticate = true,
        AutomaticChallenge = true,
        CookieName = ".AUTOADMINAUTHCOOKIE",
        LoginPath = "/Admin/Account/Login",
        CookieHttpOnly = true
    });
    ...
}
```

AdministratorController.cs:

```
[Authorize(Roles ="Super",ActiveAuthenticationSchemes ="AdministratorAuthScheme")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(string id)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(id))
    {
        return new EmptyResult();
    }
    .....
}
```

when user does not have an "Super" role,it just jump to "/Account/AccessDenied?ReturnUrl=%2FAdmin%2FAdministrator%2FEdit".

roles: user is for general user,"Admin" is for administrator,"super" is for Super Administrator which can modify or create administrator.
Can any one help me or give a reference link? 
and i'm sorry for my poor english :)

Comment: I'm searching and searching and searching..., so, i'm still searching... :(

Answer (score 2):

Use `OnApplyRedirect` Action to customize the logic.

```
app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
{
    AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
    LoginPath = new PathString("/account/login"),
    Provider = new CookieAuthenticationProvider
    {
        OnValidateIdentity = SecurityStampValidator.OnValidateIdentity<ApplicationUserManager, ApplicationUser>(
            validateInterval: TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30),
            regenerateIdentity: (manager, user) => user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(manager)),
        OnApplyRedirect = ctx =>
        {
            if (ctx.Request.Path.StartsWithSegments(new PathString("/admin")))
                ctx.Response.Redirect("/admin/account/login?ReturnUrl=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(ctx.Request.Path.ToString()));
            else
                ctx.Response.Redirect(ctx.RedirectUri);
        }
    },
});
```

Comment: how can we do that in net core 5 !?

Answer (score 0):

i don't think so you can do that with this way, the best way is to do Custom Authorization attribute then check for role or url and redirect user as you want

**Example**

```
public class CustomAuthorizeAttribute : ControllerAttribute, IAsyncActionFilter
{
    public bool IsAdmin { get; set; } = false;
    public async Task OnActionExecutionAsync(ActionExecutingContext context, ActionExecutionDelegate next)
    {
        var resultContext = await next();
        bool hasAllowAnonymous = resultContext.ActionDescriptor.EndpointMetadata.Any(em => em.GetType() == typeof(AllowAnonymousAttribute));
        bool isAuth = resultContext.HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated;

        if (!isAuth && !hasAllowAnonymous)
        {
            string redirectUrl = resultContext.HttpContext.Request.Path.Value;

            if (IsAdmin)
                resultContext.Result = new RedirectToActionResult("Index", "About", new { redirectUrl = redirectUrl, area = "Admin" });
            else
                resultContext.Result = new RedirectToActionResult("App", "Home", new { redirectUrl = redirectUrl });
        }
    }
}
```